# Finding a bound on double summation involving primes

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

I am reading a number theory proof of a result in which I am stuck on a bound.Suppose $p_1$ and $p_2$ are primes with the property that each $p_i$ satisfies $e^r \leq P_i <e^{r+1}$ and $P_1 \equiv P_2 (\mod q)$.I am trying to find a bound on the following summation: $$\sum_{p_1}\sum_{p_2} {1}$$

The given bound is  $e^r( \frac {e^r}{q}+1 )$.I am unable to prove this.Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's ignore the fact that $P_1,P_2$ are prime. The idea is that there are $e^{r+1} - e^r = (e-1)e^r$ possibilities for $P_1$, and for each of them, at most $\frac{(e-1)e^r}{q}+1$ possibilities for $P_2$ (this is an upper bound on the number of integers in the range $[e^r,e^{r+1})$ which are $\equiv a \pmod{q}$). Multiplying this together, you get the bound with $e^r$ replaced by $(e-1)e^r$.

Why the $e-1$ factors? Perhaps there was some misunderstanding in the question, since this is quite clearly the proof method which was intended.

For $P_1,P_2$ prime, the sum is actually less by a factor of roughly $r^2$.

Comment: Sorry..Can you please explain the last line?

Comment: It's just the prime number theorem. Roughly $1/r$ of the numbers of size at most $e^r$ are prime.

Comment: Ah..I more silly doubt.How do u get bound in second line?why did u add 1?

Comment: Among any $N$ consecutive numbers, at most $N/q + 1$ are divisible by $q$. There are many ways of showing that.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  +1 sorry for replying you late.I don't see why the paper which i am reading claims the bound which i have given in question.